# Issue while running exe from VBS script using Nsclient

Tags: authentication, dll, vbscript, intel

I have written a vbs script for the intel cpu vulnerability which runs completely OK when I run it manually from command line or by double clicking it.
We have an NSClient/git infra across all servers which is used by nagios to create checks and I am trying to execute this script using NSClient++.exe from command prompt. However, when I run  the file using NSClient it fails to create the log file(SA-00086--).

Here is my NSClient command from nsc.ini:

```
intel_cpu_vulnerability=C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe //NoLogo //T:60 C:\WINDOWS\NSClient\scripts\DiscoveryTool\cpu-unsafe.vbs
```

Here is my cpu-unsafe.vbs Script:

```
' VB SCript to find the Intel Processor vulnerability.
Dim Maindir, objFSO, oFile, Executable, Vulnerable, NotVulnerable, objTextFile, Readme, VStatus, StatusLine, strLine

Const ForReading = 1
Maindir = "c:\Windows\nsclient\scripts\DiscoveryTool"
Executable = "Intel-SA-00086-console.exe"
Vulnerable = "Status: This system is vulnerable."
NotVulnerable = "Status: This system is not vulnerable."
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Deleting all previous log/xml files
For Each oFile In objFSO.GetFolder(Maindir).Files 
    If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name))= "log" or LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "xml" Then
        If  oFile.Name <> "CommandLine.xml" Then
            Deleteme = Maindir+"\"+oFile
            objFSO.DeleteFile oFile
        End If
    End If
next    

'Running the Intel detector
WSHShell.Run Maindir + "\" + Executable , 0, True
Set objShell = Nothing
WScript.Sleep 3000

'Setting the logfile to read
For Each oFile In objFSO.GetFolder(Maindir).Files 
    If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name))= "log" Then
        If  oFile.Name <> "CommandLine.xml" Then
            Readme = oFile
        End If
    End If
next

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Readme, ForReading)

'Reading the logfile and determining if the prosessor is affected.
VStatus = "Undetermined"
do until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine()
    If Left(strLine, 7) = "Status:" Then
        If InStr(strLine, NotVulnerable) <> 0 then
            VStatus = "OK"
            StatusLine = strLine
        End If

        If InStr(strLine, Vulnerable) <> 0 then
            VStatus = "NOK"
            StatusLine = strLine
        End If
    End If
    If Left(strLine, 24) = "Status: Detection Error:" Then 
        VStatus = "Undetermined"
        StatusLine = strLine
    End If
loop

'The FINAL RESULTS:
If VStatus = "OK" then
    Wscript.Echo VStatus + ": Not Vulnerable  -> From File: " + StatusLine
    Wscript.Quit(1)
ElseIf VStatus = "NOK" then
    Wscript.Echo VStatus + ": Vulnerable -> From File: " + StatusLine
    Wscript.Quit(3)
Else
    Wscript.Echo VStatus + ": May be Vulnerable  -> From File: " + StatusLine
    Wscript.Quit(2)
End If


objTextFile.Close
```

To test this script you have to download [Windows Vulnerability Detection tool from Intel's Website](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27150). Once downloaded, extract the zip file and place this script inside DiscoveryTool Folder and run it by double clicking. The script will tell if your cpu is affected by the Intel® Management Engine vulnerability.

Edit: I further tried executing the .exe directly from the NSClient and it gave me Commandline.dll auth fail error.

nsc.ini command:

```
icvy=C:\WINDOWS\NSClient\scripts\DiscoveryTool\Intel-SA-00086-console.exe
```

Output:

```
l NSClient++.cpp(456) Enter command to inject or exit to terminate...
icvy
d NSClient++.cpp(1106) Injecting: icvy:
e \CheckExternalScripts.cpp(188) The command (C:\WINDOWS\NSClient\scripts\DiscoveryTool\Intel-SA-00086-console.exe) retu
rned an invalid return code: 11
d NSClient++.cpp(1142) Injected Result: WARNING 'Error: The file 'CommandLine.dll' authentication has failed.'
d NSClient++.cpp(1143) Injected Performance Result: ''
WARNING:Error: The file 'CommandLine.dll' authentication has failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the current working directory to the directory containing the executable. I was seeing the same error message until I did so. In VBScript, I gather that would look something like:

```
WSHShell.CurrentDirectory = Maindir
WSHShell.Run Maindir + "\" + Executable , 0, True
```